# Reference for Analysis book in which natural numbers constructed from sets

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, reference-request, ordinals

Could anyone suggest books on Mathematical/Real Analysis that construct natural numbers through sets not Peano axioms?

---

I find construction of natural numbers through sets more convenient. So I thought that book that uses sets, might be easier for me to understand than Peano based one.

Comment: See [**Elements of Set Theory**](https://www.amazon.com/Elements-Set-Theory-Herbert-Enderton/dp/0122384407) by Herbert B. Enderton (1977), which has an especially good treatment of what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should turn more to Set Theory / Logic books than Real analysis books.

One example is [Basic set theory](https://store.doverpublications.com/0486150739.html) from Azriel Levy. What you're looking for is the definition of ordinals and especially finite ordinals.

Comment: I find construction of natural numbers through sets more convenient. So I thought that book that uses sets, might be easier for me to understand than Peano based one.

Comment: Both offer different perspectives and indeed comparing those constructions is interesting!